# My wlan0 interface is not coming up

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wireless, raspbian-buster

I have a raspberry pi 3 that I was using as hostspot. Today I booted it and the wlan0 interface is gone when typing

```
ip a
```

When doing raspi-config and try to configure a wireless interface, I receive the message:

> No wireless interface found

I downloaded a new image of Raspbian and copied it into my SD card but still I can only see eth0. I also updated the firmware with:

```
sudo rpi-update
```

And rebooted but still, just eth0.

When I check my connected USB devices I see 4:

> - SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter,
> - SMC9514 Hub,
> - Linux Foundation root hub,
> - Keyboard

Shouldn't there be a 5th one pointing to the wlan device? Any idea what else I could check? Is perhaps my wlan chip broken?

Here is my dmesg: https://pastebin.com/k3uaJUrh

Here is my dtc: https://pastebin.com/cgWYfFjy

After checking this useful thread, it seems it is really broken ==> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=171482&sid=f7e7e556a7b52d9af452012f3d8d3aa4

Comment: Do you find with `journalctl -b` why the wlan0 interface isn't detected?

Comment: Nope. Can you point me to a line or a word that I should pay attention to please? By skimming through the output I don't see anything relevant

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` that will get new firmware for the WiFi chip. Try downloading a fresh copy of plain Raspbian or plain Raspbian Lite, write that to a new SDCard and boot it. Does WiFi work with a fresh start?

Comment: Search for `brcmfmac` when viewing journalctl. This is the wifi driver and it loads the firmware.

Comment: journalctl -b | grep brcmfmac shows nothing. The closest is btuart[313]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43430A1.hcd but I don't know if it has anything to do with it

Comment: I tried the dist-upgrade and I saw some brcm80211 firmware getting downloaded but after a reboot I still don't get the wlan0 :(. I already tried with a fresh copy of Raspbian Lite but still nothing

Comment: As others have mentioned you won't find wlan on the USB bus. To check detected devices check `/sys/class/net/` this will show interface names, even if not connected.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the WiFi adapter on RPi 3 is not on USB bus but on SDIO bus, same as the SD card. Therefore the earliest `dmesg` message proving its presence is

```
mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
```

One of the possible failure messages is

```
mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
```

If you get this message, or there is no mention of `mmc1` at all, this typically means a hardware problem which cannot be resolved in software. You'll have to get a new board.

Comment: Thanks for the information! dmesg does not show much about mmc. Here is my dmesg (note I added a 4G Dongle to get internet connectivity): https://pastebin.com/k3uaJUrh

Answer (score 1):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Then if you still have problems ask with **detail of what you have done**

Comment: Done and still nothing.

Comment: It was working yesterday. I powered it on today and the wlan0 interface is gone, no idea why. Between the moment where it worked until the moment where it did not, I haven't typed any command or did anything. That is why I am suspecting that perhaps the wlan got broken, when checking my USB bus, I see 4 devices: a SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter, a SMC9514 Hub, a  Linux Foundation root hub and the Keyboard. Does that mean my wifi is broken?

Comment: @mbuil Please edit your question and add the additional information from the comment to it.

Answer (score 0):

No interface found means your wifi_supplicant service is somehow down. Start it and if it doesn't work flash you r sdcard again withe the latest buster(or whatever you want) release.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdest thing ever (hope it helps someone):

I was fiddling with undervolting a PiZero2W and surprisingly, adding these 2 under_voltage lines of code to `/boot/firmware/config.txt` made `wlan0` disappear:

```
over_voltage=-8
over_voltage_min=-8
```

So to solve this I removed the lines and reboot. Maybe it won't help a lot of people, but it did help me.